# Why :visible and hide/show does not work? jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide, show, visible

[image: quer]

I need to toogle the main div(black one) and it should get size of leftside. If rightside is visible it should be hidden or shown when it isn't visible. I wrote following jquery but it does notwork.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#mainDiv").toggleClass("main", function(){
            if($("#rightSide").is(":visible")){
                $("#rightSide").hide('slow');
            } else{
                $("#rightSide").show('slow');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the follwoing code works but when rightside appears first apperas at the bottom of div and creates scroll for seconds. Is it possible to make that it toggles together with main div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#mainDiv").toggleClass("main");
            $("#rightSide").toggle();

    });
});
```

Comment: ToggleClass does not take 2 parameters (classname and a function) like this. https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: thanks, I understand. But how can I rewrite this?

Comment: All you are trying to do is show/hide the rightSide on a button click.

Comment: Yes and also to toggle the main div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are trying to show/hide the #rightSide on a button click. As a result you want to "collapse" and "expand" (not toggle) the #mainDiv. The collapse/expand has nothing to do with javascript or jquery. It is a CSS setting where the width and floating of all 3 divs are set such a way that the main div is as wide as the visible divs inside.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#rightSide").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#leftSide {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rightSide {
  border: 2px solid green;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
  color: darkgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

$btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  diaplay: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="leftSide">
    Left Side
  </div>
  <div id="rightSide">
    Right Side
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn">Show/Hide</button>
```